# Find out the transport request of an application

Tags: report, abap, alv, sap-basis

I Have created a application, in SAP ABAP and also I have generated a request number for that application, no I have forgot which is my request number since there are many requests in development server.

So, can someone help me how I can find out my request number, from my application.

Comment: What kind of "request number" are you talking about?

Comment: Workbench request number (Ex : EC6K900008) to transport my applications from Development Server to Testing Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you start transaction SE10, if necessary enter your user name (should be there by default) and hit Enter. You'll get a complete list if your transports, you just have to find the one, you need.
Or you start the transaction where you developed your application (you did not specify, if it is a program than SE38 or SE80, if it is a function module than SE37, SE24 for classes, etc (however in SE80 you can see everything)) enter the program name and go to menu: Goto / Object directory entry, a popup comes up, now click the button 'Lock overview'. Another popup comes up and tells you, which transport contains your object.

Comment: It took me a while, but helped me to find my request number, I have expanded each and every request, to identify my application.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to Identify all the request numbers of an object/application.

1. Open 'SE38'.
2. Provide your object/application name.
3. Click on 'Display Button'.
4. In the Menu bar click on 'Utilities'.
5. Click on 'Versions' --> 'Version Management'.

Now we can find all the request numbers of that object/application.